# crossdomain.xml and clientaccesspolicy.xml needed on sstatic.net

Tags: bug, status-completed

Silverlight image loading from Uri fails due to lack of xdomain permission files.

Needed:

- http://sstatic.net/clientaccesspolicy.xml
- http://sstatic.net/crossdomain.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been completed.